# CWE-73: External Control of File Name or Path Veracode java solution

Tags: java, filenames, filepath, veracode

Can somebody please help me know java coding solution for below Vera code canning error?

I am creating a file and passing file location as argument.

```
File file1=new File(filePath);
**CWE-73: External Control of File Name or Path**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the:

```
Validator validator = ESAPI.validator();
validator.getValidDirectoryPath(..) // to validate the directory path
validator.getValidFileName(...) // to validate the file name
```

and then use them to create your file

Comment: Thank you.Now I have to validate JavaScript code to pass through Coverity scan.My javascript code is  reading data from HTTP request.There are many instance of such codes that I need to validate using ESAPI.one example is request.getParameter("transactionType");    other code is var transactionType='<%=tranType%>'